# IEnumerable to String from DB

Tags: c#, winforms, ienumerable

In the following code I go and get data from a database. But when I repeat the action it adds another row  with the same information again.
Haven't really figured out how I could avoid it. So I hope someone could give me an example in how I could do it differently.

The button click function

```
private void btnSteg2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getData();
    mails.AddRange(DataProvider.GetMail());
    agents.AddRange(DataProvider.GetAgentsView());


    //Body
    var body = from template in mails
               where template.Template == "Steg 1"
               select template.Body;
   strBody = String.Join("", body);

    //Subject
    var subj = from template in mails
               where template.Template == "Steg 1"
               select template.Subject;
   strSub = String.Join("", subj);

    var agentNr = from FullName in agents
                  where FullName.FullName == agentId
                  select FullName.FixedNr;
    strAgentNr = String.Join("", agentNr);


    strBody = strBody.Replace("[ddate]", dateId);
    strBody = strBody.Replace("[agent]", agentId);
    strBody = strBody.Replace("[agentnr]", strAgentNr);


    strSub = strSub.Replace("[ftgnamn]", ftgId);
    strSub = strSub.Replace("[orgnr]", orgId);
    strSub = strSub.Replace("[caseid]", caseId);

    //Send_Email_Outlook(string _recipient, string _message, string _subject, string _cc, string _bcc, string accountname)
    Mail.Send_Email_Outlook(kpmail, strBody, strSub, "", "", "");
    strAgentNr = String.Empty;
    strBody = String.Empty;
    strSub = String.Empty;
}
```

Example of how the i get the data.

```
  public class MailItem : EntityDB, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private const string TableName = "MAILTEMPLATE";
        private static SchemaJS Schema = null;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MailItem()
        {
            InitializeNew();
        }

        public MailItem(DataRowJS DRow)
        {
            base.DRow = DRow;
            base.DRow.Schema.TableName = TableName;
        }


        public string Template
        {
            get { return DRow.ToStr("TEMPLATE"); }
            set
            {
                DRow["TEMPLATE"] = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Template");
            }
        }
        public string Subject
        {
            get { return DRow.ToStr("SUBJECT"); }
            set
            {
                DRow["SUBJECT"] = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Subject");
            }
        }
        public string Body
        {
            get { return DRow.ToStr("BODY"); }
            set
            {
                DRow["BODY"] = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Body");
            }
        }
```

At first i thought i could use the `strBody =  String.Empty;` to clear the string and avoid so it wont increase with another body for the email after each button press.. The reason for `String.Join` is that i haven't found another way to get it to a string.

I'm kinda stuck and appreciate  any assistance.  Hope the information above is enough to understand my issue.

**EDIT**

Solved the issue by not calling the `mails.AddRange` over and over again.
And `body.First();` was a better choice as Camilo Terevinto pointed out.

Comment: Well, `mails.AddRange(DataProvider.GetMail());` will keep adding the items obtained. If you don't want duplicates use `mail = DataProvider.GetMail();` instead

Comment: To get the string, I'm pretty sure you  are looking for `strBody = body.First()`. You may want to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations)